# How can you use AngularFire and Firebase to authenticate an admin route?

Tags: firebase, roles, angularfire

I am trying to achieve role based authentication for a particular admin view using ngRoute. There is an example of [authenticating with routers](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/user-auth.md#authenticating-with-routers) in the AngularFire docs, but it does not take into account a user who has an admin role.

I am using Firebase to store admin by user id:

```
admin {
    <some-uid>: true,
    <another-uid>: true
}
```

From AngularFire docs:

```
// for ngRoute
app.run(["$rootScope", "$location", function($rootScope, $location) {
  $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function(event, next, previous, error) {
    // We can catch the error thrown when the $requireSignIn promise is rejected
    // and redirect the user back to the home page
    if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
      $location.path("/home");
    }
  });
}]);

app.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when("/home", {
    // the rest is the same for ui-router and ngRoute...
    controller: "HomeCtrl",
    templateUrl: "views/home.html",
    resolve: {
      // controller will not be loaded until $waitForSignIn resolves
      // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the example above
      "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
        // $waitForSignIn returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
        return Auth.$waitForSignIn();
      }]
    }
  }).when("/account", {
    // the rest is the same for ui-router and ngRoute...
    controller: "AccountCtrl",
    templateUrl: "views/account.html",
    resolve: {
      // controller will not be loaded until $requireSignIn resolves
      // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the example above
      "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
        // $requireSignIn returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
        // If the promise is rejected, it will throw a $stateChangeError (see above)
        return Auth.$requireSignIn();
      }]
    }
  });
}]);

app.controller("HomeCtrl", ["currentAuth", function(currentAuth) {
  // currentAuth (provided by resolve) will contain the
  // authenticated user or null if not signed in
}]);

app.controller("AccountCtrl", ["currentAuth", function(currentAuth) {
  // currentAuth (provided by resolve) will contain the
  // authenticated user or null if not signed in
}]);
```